# Confusing Nulls in c

Tags: c++, c, null

Please explain following things in regard of C or C++:

- The null pointer
- The internal representation of a null pointer
- The null pointer constant - 0
- The NULL macro
- The ASCII null character (NUL)
- The null string ("").

Comment: Ehmmm...No? What is your question? This is something you could easily look up yourself either online or in good textbooks. Is there something in particular you don't understand and would like us to clarify?

Comment: It's all here http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=null

Comment: Hmm, I want to know is there any kind of big difference in them, as I was asked this question in an interview that what is the difference and I really can't explain the differences between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null pointer is a pointer that doesn't point to any object.

The internal representation is not specified, and specifically doesn't have to be all bits zero.

The value 0 can be converted to a null pointer.

The NULL macro is defined as a value that can be converted to a null pointer, in C++ it is often just `0` and in C often `(void*)0`, but can be other values as well if the implementation decides so.

The NUL character is a character that has the value `0` or `'\0'`.

The string `""` is just an empty string.

Comment: FWIW, an invalid pointer is also a pointer that points to no object.

Comment: Yes, and a null pointer is also an invalid pointer. :-)